# Storing Rails model data in JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get data from my model into JavaScript arrays, but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var s_array = new Array();
  var img_array = new Array();
  var num_array = new Array();
  var x_array = new Array();
  var y_array = new Array();
  var p_array = new Array();

  <% @data.each do |data| %>
    s_array.push(<%= (data.s) %>);
    img_array.push(<%= (data.img) %>);
    num_array.push(<%= (data.num) %>);
    x_array.push(<%= (data.x) %>);
    y_array.push(<%= (data.y) %>);
    p_array.push(<%= (data.p) %>);
  <% end %>
</script>
```

Comment: For string you must use quotation like this line: s_array.push("<%= (data.s) %>");

Comment: Why not just use JSON? That aside, not simply mirroring the data in the JS is already suspicious--why have separate arrays when you already have objects?

Comment: @DaveNewton how would you access the object data with JS?

Comment: Same way you always do with JS? Your JSON would be the array of objects, thus JS objects, etc. Just dump the JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't print JS code in your views. That'll create a strong coupling between your front and back ends and it's ugly. If you want a simple approach, you can use a data tag and transform your model's data into JSON, which you can then simply consume in JS.

`@data` can be serialized using `@data.to_json`. If that's coming directly from the model, remember that you can override the `as_json(options)` method to control how the Active Record object gets rendered into a JSON object.

In your HTML, you can just add a data tag. For example, you could place this in your view:

```
<div id="data_model_name" data-your-data="<%= @data.to_json %>">
```

Back in JS, you can do:

```
var yourData = $('#data_model_name').data('your-data')
```

And retrieve the info.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense